# Python - get slice index

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Is it possible to get index values (start,end) of a slice? For example

```
In [1]: s = "Test string"
In [2]: s[-6:] # get slice indexes (5,11)
Out[2]: 'string'


In [3]: s = "Another test string"
In [4]: s[8:] # get slice indexes (8,19)
Out[4]: 'test string'
```

In other words, I don't need the substring itself but only the indexes as a tuple (start,end).

Comment: `len(s) - 6, len(s)` and `8, len(s)` are what you want here. Not really sure what you're after - why do you need these?

Answer (score 16):

You can use python's [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) object like so:

```
In [23]: s = "Test string"

In [24]: slice(-6, None).indices(len(s))
Out[24]: (5, 11, 1)

In [25]: s = "Another test string"

In [26]: slice(8, None).indices(len(s))
Out[26]: (8, 19, 1)
```

EDIT: using Eric's improvement to use None instead of len(s) for the stop argument

Comment: Instead of `len(s)`, you can use `None` here for the `stop` argument

Answer (score 3):

```
class SliceGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.size = len(inner)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index.indices(self.size)[:2]
```

```
>>> SliceGetter("Test string")[-6:]
(5, 11)
>>> SliceGetter("Another test string")[8:]
(8, 19)
```

Comment: This is reinventing the wheel somewhat.

Comment: @Lattyware: Not really - it just allows you to use syntactic sugar to create slice objects.

Comment: I get it, and it's a cool little idea, but I don't think it really makes the code clearer, and the ``slice()`` built-in does the job.

Answer (score 0):

define your own function :

```
In [119]: def start_end(strs,x):
    if x>0:
        return x,len(strs)  
    else:
        return len(strs)+x,len(strs)
   .....:     

In [120]: start_end("Test String",-6)
Out[120]: (5, 11)

In [122]: func("Another test string",8)
Out[122]: (8, 19)
```